# Toys for a 1 year old

Tags: toddler, infant, toys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to better engage myself with my 15 month old](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6109/how-to-better-engage-myself-with-my-15-month-old)

This is my first child, and she is getting now 1 year old.

What type of type of toys can a father or mother to play to help her grow mentally and psychologically, and entertain her at the same time?

Comment: Regarding the add-on question in your update, please put that in a separate question because it's a totally different question. Or, even better, check out some of the [existing answers about television and toddlers](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toddler+television).

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun, Thanks a lot :)), I made some research on the internet, and added an answer, please check it, and tell what do you think

Comment: I think your answer is pretty good (especially if you include hyperlinks to the sources). But I also think that you're asking 2 distinct questions, and they should be split up into two posts. In fact, if you look at our [questions tagged "television"](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television) you will probably find an existing question, to which you could post your answer. It would be more "at home" there than here (especially if you remove your update from this question).

Comment: You can probably tell that we try to be friendly, but we also try to [maintain high quality](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/about) in the content. I'm telling you the above to improve the answer quality of each of your questions, not to pick on what you've already contributed :-)

Comment: Actually, you are very true, I'll consider that in my next posts :)

Comment: As you can see, I've edited this question to make it more focused - and by doing that, identified an existing question with appropriate answers for you! As for the TV part of your question, please check if it's not already answered elsewhere. You can click the `edit` link to copy your answer if you want to re-post it under an existing question.

Answer (score 3):

The child is one year old. At this stage it's learning from everything around it. Try to give the child different (but safe) objects and see what they gets engrossed in without trying to push them in a particular direction and take it from there.

For example, different coloured clothes, dolls, moving objects like cars, building blocks. They don't even have to be "toys", just any objects that pique the imagination. Remember that everything is new and educative at this stage.

Regarding play. Touch, hold and cuddle your child as much as you can till the age of 5. This is known to have psychological and mental benefits going forward. The same applies to rough and tumble play (safely) in parks and indoor playgrounds or even in the house. The bonding benefits are immense too.

If the weather permits, allow the child to go out and play with them. A ball or wheelable vehicle would help.

At this age kids generally don't play with other kids, but indulge in parallel play, so don't worry too much about that aspect.

Lastly, rather than expensive toys, give the child your time, become a child while playing with the child.

Comment: And no or very little TV.

Comment: Agree with Dave on TV. That may mean changing your TV habits too.

Comment: Another great answer from you alok :), keep the good responses.

Comment: @DaveClarke, regarding the TV, would you please elaborate more, what are the pros and cons of watching a TV for the child?

Comment: Have a look at: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6999/is-it-reasonable-common-for-a-daycare-to-show-tv-shows-during-the-day/

Comment: I appreciate your help Dave, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Alok has answered question part, however, there is an important thing I need to refer to, which is watching TV for kids.

After doing some research, here are my results:

According to some research of "**American Academy of Pediatrics**", under the title of "***BABIES AND TODDLERS SHOULD LEARN FROM PLAY, NOT SCREENS***", those are the key findings:

1. Many video programs for infants and toddlers are marketed as “educational,” yet evidence does not support this.
2. Quality programs are educational for children only if they
   understand the content and context of the video. Studies
   consistently find that children over 2 typically have this
   understanding.
3. Unstructured play time is more valuable for the developing brain
   than electronic media.
4. Children learn to think creatively, problem solve, and develop
   reasoning and motor skills at early ages through unstructured,
   unplugged play.
5. Free play also teaches them how to entertain themselves.
6. Young children learn best from—and need—interaction with humans, not
   screens.
7. Parents who watch TV or videos with their child may add to the
   child’s understanding, but children learn more from live
   presentations than from televised ones.
8. When parents are watching their own programs, this is “background
   media” for their children.
9. It distracts the parent and decreases parent-child interaction.
10. Its presence may also interfere with a young child’s learning from
    play and activities.
11. Television viewing around bedtime can cause poor sleep habits and
    irregular sleep schedules, which can adversely affect mood, behavior
    and learning.
12. Young children with heavy media use are at risk for delays in
    language development once they start school, but more research is
    needed as to the reasons.

**

- **The report also recommends that parents and caregivers:**

**

1. Set media limits for their children before age 2, bearing in mind that the "**American Academy of Pediatrics**" discourages media use for this age group.
2. Have a strategy for managing electronic media if they choose to engage their children with it; Instead of screens, opt for supervised independent play for infants and young children during times that a parent cannot sit down and actively engage in play with the child. For example, have the child play
   with nesting cups on the floor nearby while a parent prepares dinner;
3. Avoid placing a television set in the child’s bedroom; and
4. Recognize that their own media use can have a negative effect on children.

Comment: I can't help but think that the recommendations to avoid media for children of this age group are exaggerated so as to purposefully overshoot the goal. IOW saying "please no media!" will encourage parents to limit it to a resonable amount. I'm not advocating jacking them in, but there's plenty of redeeming media for kids these age that isn't on Disney or Nick.